# malformed classname in Scala

Tags: scala

Why am I getting malformed classname error in REPL?

define parent class

```
scala> class Fruit {
     | def FruitMethod = "f"
     | }
defined class Fruit
```

define child class

```
scala> class Orange extends Fruit {
     | def OrangeMethod = "o"
     | }
defined class Orange
```

testing variance

```
scala> class MyContainer[+A](val a: A)(implicit manifest: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) {
     |   def contents = manifest.runtimeClass.getSimpleName
     | }
defined class MyContainer

scala> val fruitBasket: MyContainer[Fruit] = new MyContainer[Orange](new Orange())
fruitBasket: MyContainer[Fruit] = MyContainer@7546be68

scala> fruitBasket.contents
java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
  at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1330)
  at MyContainer.contents(<console>:13)
  ... 29 elided
```

Comment: Interestingly this works in Ammonite (but fails in scala repl) !

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, fixed in JDK9 (!) https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034 https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5425

Comment: I also see this is a scala koan: https://github.com/FPerezP/scala-koans/blob/master/AboutTypeVariance.scala#L20-L35 or https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/type_variance the plot thickens!